# USB Drivers for Dragon Touch E70 (or how to install an APK from PC on this device?)

Tags: installation, tablet, apk, usb-drivers

I purchased a Dragon Touch E70 tablet from Tablet Express. I am developing an app, but I cannot get Eclipse to detect the device. I can't find where to download drivers for this device either. Any ideas, or other ways to get the app on my tablet for testing?

Comment: What OS are you using on your PC?

Comment: No need for any USB drivers. Go to your Eclipse workspace -> your app that you are developing -> bin. There you will find your app's APK file. Transfer that file into your tablet and test it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using a DragonTouch K10 and found this question - The issue I discovered I was having was that I needed to enable developer tools on the device. I went to Settings>System>About Tablet, then tapped the Build number 7 times to turn them on. Then my SDK was able to detect it with the drivers I had installed.